# My relatives do love to bind. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I can't hear a word you say.
>   I haven't come to aid.
>   I can however help you sway,
>   And maybe turn a head.
>   I can be loud, I can be sweet.
>   But I do not speak.
>   Made for seeing, I don't see.
>   Attention's what I seek.
>   While to you my pretty case I wish to submit.
>   My relatives do love to bind.
>   But I will never commit.

**Who am I?**

Comment: Are any of the below the correct answer?

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the answer:

> Music

I can't hear a word you say.

> Music doesn't listen to you.

I haven't come to aid.

> Music just is

I can however help you sway,

> Dance

And maybe turn a head.

> Some people are real 'head-turners when dancing or singing

I can be loud, I can be sweet.

> Different genres of music. Some are loud (metal for example, others are sweet - love ballads)

But I do not speak.

> It doesnt speak in the literal sense

Made for seeing, I don't see.

> A persons taste in music allows you to see much about them, but music itself is incapable of seeing

Attention's what I seek.

> Music has always been something that gains attention, from the bards in times of old, right up to now.

While to you my pretty case I wish to submit.
My relatives do love to bind.
But I will never commit.

> The spoken word, poetry and so on, all obey strict rules, music however does not and can be whatever it wants, and is ever changing

Answer (score 0):

May be it is (though a partial answer)

> A puppet (show with ventriloquism)

As,

I can't hear a word you say.

> a doll /puppet cannot hear what the puppeteer says

I haven't come to aid.

> ... (To be provided)

I can however help you sway,

> with the lyrics and associated songs, perhaps

And maybe turn a head.

> as a part of show

I can be loud, I can be sweet.

> Usually puppet shows are supposed to be this

But I do not speak.

> A puppet is dumb

Made for seeing, I don't see.

> Well, this is fully applicable for a puppet

Attention's what I seek.

> Is natural

While to you my pretty case I wish to submit.

> Perhaps, after a show, the instruments are packed in a nice case

My relatives do love to bind.

> Usually many a dolls are tied to strings / sticks for a play

But I will never commit.

> ... (To be provided)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be

> a rumor

I can't hear a word you say.

> A rumor is something against which you can't argue or defend yourself.

I haven't come to aid.

> A rumor is most of the time something that will not help you at all.

I can however help you sway,
And maybe turn a head.

> A rumor may sway or turn people's head by changing their opinion about somebody.

I can be loud, I can be sweet.

> A rumor can be spread by everybody or being insidious !

But I do not speak.

> The rumor itself do not speak.

Made for seeing, I don't see.

> I don't know for this one :/

Attention's what I seek.

> A rumor's goal is definitely to spread and to get the more attention it can.

While to you my pretty case I wish to submit.

> A rumor is a matter of discussion.

My relatives do love to bind.

> Bad reputation and gossips, rumor's best friends, will be bind to you and you will not be able to get rid of it.

But I will never commit.

> A rumor never commits its peddlers.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be

> A PHONOGRAPH

I can't hear a word you say.

> Its a machine which produces sounds and don't listen itself

I haven't come to aid.

> Music is a Therapy :)

I can however help you sway,

> Put on a CD sway on the beats

And maybe turn a head.

> turn the head on phonograph to play the record

I can be loud, I can be sweet.

> After its played, Thats the type of music you might get.

But I do not speak.

> definitely not by itself

Made for seeing, I don't see.

> self explanatory

Attention's what I seek.

> in a party or at home, it wants you to play something

While to you my pretty case I wish to submit.

> They come in beautiful cases

My relatives do love to bind.

> relatives referring to Cassette/ Records played on it. Its binds and then is played.

But I will never commit.

> It will not commit to play a single record cd, but will change a record time to time.

Answer (score -1):

Could you be a

> HONK?

I can't hear a word you say.

> A honk does’t hear anything

I haven't come to aid.

> Honks don’t provide physical assistance in doing anything

I can however help you sway,

> Sway in traffic

And maybe turn a head.

> Other drivers notice you

I can be loud,

> Obviously

I can be sweet.

> [this](http://sorrythanksiloveyou.com/food/oils-and-accompaniments/honk-mustard) looks sweet

But I do not speak.

> Obviously

Made for seeing, I don't see.

> For other drivers to see you

Attention's what I seek.

> Obviously

While to you my pretty case I wish to submit.

> no idea

My relatives do love to bind.

> Binding brakes

But I will never commit.

> no idea